# How can I get the insulation batts back up above the finished attic ceiling?

Tags: insulation, attic, attic-conversion

I have a finished attic. The finished room has drywall screwed directly to the roof rafters. There were insulation batts installed between rafters initially, but it's a steep slope and most of them have now slid down into a pile behind the knee wall.

I tried pushing them back up but they jam.

Even if I do manage to get them up, I not sure how I will prevent them from falling again.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to leave them there and add more?

Comment: Those batts are sized to be a tight fit between the rafters, or should have been...

Comment: Spray foam might be your solution.....professionally sprayed insulation foam is one of the best!

Comment: @LimoDRIVER except for the off-gassing from the foam as it cures...

Comment: I would agree with the driver, foam may be the best choice without removing the Sheetrock and stapling or strapping.

Comment: Hmm. Sliding down is unusual if remotely properly installed, but becomes more likely if they became waterlogged due to poor vapor control (condensation - moisture from inside house) or a roof leak.

Comment: > "remotely properly installed" yep that'd be the problem. Total incompetence. Everything in the house is done improperly, hence me spending time to fix it.